# How to find out if an individual trace succeeded or not

Tags: ether, openethereum, transaction-trace

I understand that I can find if a transaction succeeded or not via the receipt `status` field. I'd like to do the same for individual traces, since a root tx can succeed, but child calls can fail.

My goal is to come up with a complete record from a transaction of ETH or token debits and credits by address resulting from a transaction.

See here for an example from Etherscan:

[image]

When I pull traces with the `trace_transaction` RPC call, I get something like this for each individual trace object returned:

```json
{
    'action': {
        'callType': 'call',
        'from': '0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'gas': '0x25ce48',
        'input': '0x3dea52fc000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000077e772392b600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
        'to': '0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'value': '0x0'
    },
    'blockHash': '0xXXXXXXXXX',
    'blockNumber': 6000030,
    'result': {'gasUsed': '0x2532ed', 'output': '0x'},
    'subtraces': 1,
    'traceAddress': [],
    'transactionHash': '0xXXXXXXXXXX',
    'transactionPosition': 45,
    'type': 'call'
}
```

So unless the failure is using too much gas, I don't see how I could determine if it failed (and therefore all it's child calls), which is what I'm trying to do.

Any ideas on how I can find this?